# Is there any way I can relate multiple users(different type) from my custom user model to my other models?

Tags: django

I am trying to make to take advantage of django's authentication system, but having difficult time with user models

I tried to extend my user model using these tutorial: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html. It was easy to follow and understandable until I got stuck while relating my newly extended user model to my existing models. My model has fields that relate to two types of my users at the same time, and I am using tuple within the field to differentiate my users. I searched for answers but the solutions are generic and I keep getting clash error messages when I tried to migrate.

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'Registral'),
        (2, 'Teacher'),
        (3, 'Parent'),
        (4, 'Admin'),)

    user_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES)

    telephone = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Registral(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True)
    Admin_created=models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Parent(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    primary_key=True)
    parent_of = models.ForeignKey('Student',on_delete=models.CASCADE)



class Student(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null=True)
    grade = models.IntegerField()
    member_of = models.ForeignKey('communicate.Class', 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    contact_parent = models.ForeignKey('Parent', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    registered_by = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

How to migrate without error

Comment: Please, share the error traceback you get.

Comment: register.Parent.registered_by: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'Parent.registered_by' clashes with reverse query name for 'Parent.user'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Parent.registered_by' or 'Parent.user'.
register.Registral.Admin_created: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'Registral.Admin_created' clashes with reverse query name for 'Registral.user'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Registral.Admin_created' or 'Registral.user'.